# How to limit Bootstrap Datepicker date view to just Year

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-datepicker

I am running Bootstrap 3.3.6 (latest) and Datepicker plugin 1.6.0 (latest).

I want the date box to only accept and display year between a certain range (in my current case 2014, 2015, and 2016).

I have this customization in place:

```
$('#my-container .my-class').datepicker({
  //format: " yyyy", // does not work
  minViewMode: "years",
  maxViewMode: "years",
  startDate: '01/01/2014',
  endDate: new Date(),
  startView: "year" //does not work
});
```

Is it possible to limit the input and display to just a 4-digit year?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Try this solution :*

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    format: " yyyy",
    viewMode: "years", 
    minViewMode: "years",
    startDate: '2014',
    endDate: new Date(),
});
```

See **[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Shady_Alset/ze36omz0/)**. *I hope it works for you, thanks.*

Comment: Excellent @ShadyAlset. Worked perfectly. Greatly appreciate the solution !

Comment: External resouces link of jsFiddle may be expired. It is not working now.